# Ubuntu File Manager, replacement for Nautilus

Tags: file-management, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and searching for a good file manager to replace Nautilus, based on the following criteria:

- Overall performance

  - Copying many small files needs to be fast
  - Searching files should be fast
  - Displaying many items needs to be fast, ideally with on-demand loading (Nautilus is quite bad at this point)
- Straightforward user interface

  - Basically like Nautilus' user interface before Ubuntu 18 and the switch to GNOME
  - Should not be too "laggy"

Comment: Note that you will probably not be able to completely get rid of Nautilus unless you switch to a different desktop environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at Nemo (https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/07/how-to-replace-nautilus-with-nemo-file.html), which was forked from Nautilus before Nautilus was 'simplified' to death.  I don't know if it will meet your criteria for performance.

Comment: Performance is better than Nautilus, so I guess it meets my criteria :D